# jmeter: evaluate the values of JSON values

Tags: jmeter, jsonpath, json-path-expression, jsonassert

I am trying to test my API response using JSON assertion in JMeter, but couldn't find out on how to achieve it. The API returns 2 values, and I need to check if the difference between these two value are consistent

API response:

```
{
  "start": "12759898",
  "end": "12759907"
}
```

[image]

I've tried like the above, but it seems to be wrong, as its a JSONPath variable.
Could anyone guide on how to evaluate these values? is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a job for [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion)

1. Add JSR223 Assertion as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
   def start = response.start as long
   def end = response.end as long
   def delta = end - start

   if (delta != 10) {
       AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
       AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Expected: 10, got: ' + delta)
   }
   ```

   If the difference between `start` and `end` will not be equal to `10` - the request will be marked as failed.

   [image]

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)